# ArcMap Models and Scripts do not appear in Toolbox

Tags: model, arcgis, arcpy, arcmap

I created several tools using ModelBuilder in ArcMap, and they are saved in a toolbox in my default ArcMap directory.  To allow other users to access the toolbox, I copied everything to the ArcGIS subdirectory of the Shared drive.  I can access the tools in that toolbox just fine no matter what terminal I log into, but when I looked over someone else's shoulder while he was trying to access the tools in my toolbox, the tools would not show.  The toolbox was there, but there was no "plus sign" to open to show the tools.  I made sure to change the Security settings so he can access everything.  Did I miss something?  Will I have to use geoprocessing services or do something else so other users can see my tools?

Comment: Are you and the other user using the same version of ArcGIS for Desktop?

Comment: Thank you for your response, Gary.  That is what the problem is.  All the boxes where I am have ArcMap 10.2, and he has ArcMap 10.0.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the other user is using a version of ArcGIS for Desktop that is at least as new as the version you used to create the models.

Comment: Thank you, Gary.  A few minutes ago I saved the toolbox as a Version 10.0 toolbox so he can open it.